# How to show that $n^{-1}S_n \rightarrow 0$ with probability 1?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X_1,X_2,....$ are independent and uniformly bounded and $E[X_n]=0$. Use the first Borel Cantelli Lemma and Chebyshev's inequality, prove that $n^{-1}S_n \rightarrow 0$ with probability 1.

I know that convergence in probability 1 implies convergence in probability. This means I need to show that $P[|n^{-1}S_n| \geq \epsilon~ i.o]=0$.

By Chebyshev inequality, $P[|S_n| \geq n\epsilon]\leq \frac{E[|S_n|]}{n \epsilon}$ . I am little confused how to use first Borel Cantelli Lemma here. Can anyone suggest some hints?

Comment: What is $S_n?{}{}{}$

Comment: You should do this for all the questions you've asked. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

First, you can write
$$
P(|S_n|>n\varepsilon) = P(|S_n|^4>n^4\varepsilon^4)  \leq \frac{1}{n^4\varepsilon^4}E(S_n^4).
$$
Second, let $|X_1|\leq M$ for some positive number $M$. Then
$$E(S_n^4) = E(\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^n X_iX_jX_kX_l) = \sum_{i=1}^nE(X_i^4)+{4 \choose 2}\sum_{i\neq j=1}^nE(X_i^2X_j^2) \leq nM^4+ {4 \choose 2}n^2M^4.$$
The second equality in the last display is due to the fact that the contribution of other terms are zero. Can you complete the proof from here?

Comment: Yes, I showed that $\sum P(|S_n|>n \epsilon)< \infty$, then by first Borel Cantelli lemma, $ P(|n^{-1}S_n|> \epsilon~i.o)=0$

Comment: Great! Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

HINT: I suspect you will need a different inequality than the application of Chebyshev's inequality you have right now.  You only have a factor of $\frac 1n$ in the bound on $P(|S_n| > n \varepsilon)$, so I don't think you can use Borel-Cantelli.  You might consider using the fact that each $X_i$ is bounded to get a bound on a higher moment of $S_n$.